# A data diff tool for finding the difference between two Access MDB Files

Tags: ms-access, diff

I have two different MDB files [with the same structure]. Is there an existing tool that can report the difference between the two files [row by row]?

I found a program called "MDBDiff" on SF, however the program is no longer available for download.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the following page and go down a bit for a list of utilities to compare Access databases
http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/thirdparty.htm  One of those might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thats what i'm looking for. but they aren't free.

Comment: If you are trying to compare data you could write your own code by running through the Tabledefs collection to get the list of the tables, then the Fields collection to get a list of fields.  Then, still inside VBA, from the list of fields create SQL code which compares the fields in the two tables based on the primary key.  You'd also need to check for records present in one table and not the other and vice versa.

Answer (score 9):

I've made an [AccdbMerge](https://ksdbmerge.tools/accdbmerge) utility that is able to compare data and programming objects as well. In scope of "row by row" comparison - it will show what records were added/modified/removed, for modified records it will highlight fields with updated values.

Comment: free version can tell basic diff and pro version has all the benefits.

Comment: The app doesn't start after install for me on windows 10.

Comment: @AlexanderPuchkov thanks for letting me know; there is some delay on the first start but I can't reproduce total silence. Delay could be caused by MS Access availability check - it is required to make it work. Lot of things can go wrong, for example by antivirus software or windows updates, I run test suite and virustotal check only during release. I am not checking each Windows/Office update. If you think it still can be useful for you and interested in making it work - please contact me by email support(at)db-merge-tools.net, I'll be happy to assist.

Comment: Worked fine for me on Win10

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the same (basically use DIFF to see differences row by row) so

1)  I exported all the tables:

Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

```
Private Sub ExportAllTables()
    Dim myDatabase As Database
    Dim myTableDef As TableDef

    Dim strTableName As String

    Set myDatabase = CurrentDb
    For Each myTableDef In myDatabase.TableDefs
        DoEvents
        strTableName = myTableDef.Name
        DoCmd.TransferText _
            acExportDelim, _
            , _
            strTableName, _
            Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\DeskTop\dump\" & strTableName & ".CSV", _
            True
    Next myTableDef
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

2) concatenated them into one file

```
type *.csv > all.txt
```

CAT will do as well if you have it

3) diff'ed them

```
diff all.txt all2.txt
```

Comment: I've done a similar thing for a relatively static database where I scripted an export for every table and then each text file goes into the git repository where you can then use standard git diff tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SQL Data Compare from Redgate, http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm

and then use this trick,
http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?p=15296#15296

Comment: I was thinking of something of an smaller utility [similar to diff]

Comment: Link to red gate form doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know what is the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but this tool looks like it would do the job http://www.datanamic.com/download/download-datadiff-for-msaccess.html